# multiprocessing.Process target executing only 2 out of 3 times

Tags: python, fork, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the multiprocessing library to launch a `Process` in parallel with the main one. I use the `target` argument at the initialisation to specify a function to execute. But the function is not executed approximatively 1 out of 3 times.

After digging into the multiprocessing library and using monkey patches to debug, I found out that the method `_bootstrap` of `BaseProcess` (the `Process` class inherits from `BaseProcess`), that is supposed to call the function specified in the target parameters at the initialisation, was not called when the method `start()` of the Process was called.

As my OS is Ubuntu 18.04, the default method to start the process is `fork`. So the Popen used to launch the process is in the file `popen_fork.py` of the multiprocessing library. And in this Popen class, the method `_launch` is calling `os.fork()` and then calling the Process's `_bootstrap` method.

With a monkey patch, I found out that the code supposed to be executed in the child process is not executed at all, and this is why the function specified in the `target` parameter when initializing the process was not executed when the method `start()` was called.

It is not possible to reproduce the problem in a simpler environment than the one I am working on. But here is some code that represents what I am doing, and what is my problem :

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


class A:

    def __init__(self, manager):
        # manager is an object created by registering it in
        # multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager, so it is made for interprocess
        # communication
        self.manager = manager

        self.p = Process(target=self.process_method, args=(self.manager, ))

    def start(self):
        self.p.start()

    def process_method(self, manager):
        # This is the method that is not executed 2 out of 3 times
        print("(A.process_method) Entering method")
        c = 0
        while True:
            print(f"(A.process_method) Sending message : c = {c}")
            manager.on_reception(f"c = {c}")
            time.sleep(5)


class Manager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = None
        self.unread_msg = False

    def on_reception(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.unread_msg = True

    def get_last_msg(self):
        if self.unread_msg:
            self.unread_msg = False
            return self.msg
        else:
            return None



if __name__ == "__main__":
    BaseManager.register("Manager", Manager)
    bm = BaseManager()
    bm.start()
    manager = bm.Manager()

    a = A(manager)
    a.start()
    while True:
        msg = manager.get_last_msg()
        if msg is not None:
            print(msg)
```

The method that should be executed every time is `A.process_method`. In this example, it is executed every time, but in my environment, it is not.

**Does anyone ever had this problem and knows how to fix it ?**

Comment: Can you produce a simple test case which demonstrates the problem? Try to make it as minimal as possible (just a few lines of code) such that you can post it here.

Comment: I added some code to demonstrate the problem. I hope it will helps to resolve the issue

Comment: I don't really know how to run your code. Make it complete and self-contained.

Comment: you need to show _how_ you're running the code. what do you do with `A`?

Comment: I added an some code to show what I do with A, this is a simplified example of what I am doing inside the project I am working on.

Comment: Make the code as simple and minimal as possible. Just make it a single code snippet (for a single file, not multiple files). Also, explain, when you run your code snippet, what is the expected output, and what output do you get instead.

Comment: I don't see how your code illustrates the problem. What should the code do? What output and behavior would you expect? What output and behavior do you get instead?

Comment: Now you say "In this example, it is executed every time, but in my environment, it is not.". But that is exactly what I was asking for: An example where we see the problem. Try to come up with such an example. Maybe start with your own code, and remove unrelated stuff as much as possible. Your current example is not helpful if it does not illustrate the problem.

Comment: After digging more, I found out that the issue was linked to a flask server that was started in a Thread before the Process I was having trouble with. Flask and my Process are using the logging package, and this can cause a [deadlock when launching Processes](https://bugs.python.org/issue37429). Now i run the flask server in a Process and everything is running like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more, I found out that a flask server was launched in Thread and not in a Process. I changed it to run in a Process instead of a Thread, and now everything is running as it is supposed to.

Both Flask and my Process are using the logging package. And this can cause a [deadlock when launching a new Process](https://bugs.python.org/issue37429).